# Does "fairly" mean "relatively" or some level between them?

Tags: meaning, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/w6mdjf4nVTA?t=132)

> Initially the gradient is positive and `fairly` constant, but for it drops to zero at the peak, it then becomes negative for a period before returning to zero.

Cambridge gives this [explanation](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fairly) about `fairly`

> more than average, but less than very

which seems not to be the case here.

[image]

assume the initial part is the time frame between the starting point, shown above, and somewhere shown below

[image]

Technically, in the initial part, the gradient (the slop of the orange line) is not a constant. but it could be viewed as a constant, when compared to the one shown below.

[image]

If the meaning "more than average" is taken, where is the average? So, it seems that "fairly" mean "relatively" in this case, is my understanding right?

Comment: It isn't talking about the average gradient of the graph, it means fairly relative to the gradient at the rest of the points in the graph. A better definition would be - more than a little; to some degree [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fairly)

Comment: A typical thing a mathematician might say is "for small angles, _tan(x)_ is **fairly close** to _sin(x)_."  The lecturer means it in this mathematical sense: "approximately", "quite", without being specific.  You can indeed see it's pretty close: he just means "straight-ish", and is contrasted to the part where the curve visibly changes direction.  (He also doesn't mean the dictionary sense using "average", nor any mathematical meaning of average.)

Answer (score 3):

'fairly' = 'somewhat'

It's an indeterminate positive indicating that something is positively true - but it does not quantize how much it is true.

Other Synonyms = 'a little', 'slightly'

Fairly is stronger than 'a little', and stronger than 'slightly' but a weaker comparison than 'frequently'

Truth is a binary concept in logic - but has degrees in language. My guess at the following, going from weakest to strongest
'slightly'
'a little'
'somewhat'
'fairly'
'commonly'
'frequently'
'almost always'
'solely' / 'always'
'